# Change class using jQuery slider UI

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, slider, range

I would like to use the jQuery slider UI to change the class on a separate element.

The slider would for example have 10 steps, and for each step there would be a corresponding class to applied to the target element.

For example:

when the slider is in position 2, the element has the class of ".step-two"
when the slider is in position 6, the element has the class of ".step-six"

I would also like the classes to change while the user moves the slider, and not just on release. Is this possible?

```
    $('#slider').slider({
    value:0,
    min: 0,
    max: 110,
    step: 11,

    slide: function(event,ui){

        if (ui.value<0) { 
            $('#object').addClass('step-one');
        } else if (ui.value<10) { 
             $('#object' ).addClass('step-two');

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried already, and what doesn't work ? Have you read the documentation ?

Comment: Sure, its possible! You should look at this triggered event and then implement your own logic: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change

Comment: i have updated the post to show what i have so far, i believe i'm on the right track, but not sure if i'm barking up the wrong tree. in t his example i have 11 steps... as opposed to ten.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little help on how to do it, why you would want this is beyond me:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    step: 1,
    range: false,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#someotherElement").removeClass().addClass('step_'+ui.value); //adds class step_1 -> step_10 etc
    }
});​
```

Or if you have to use "one", "two" etc. use an array:

```
var array = ['one','two','three','four','five','six'....etc]

$("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 1,
    range: false,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#someotherElement").removeClass().addClass('step_'+array[ui.value]);
    }
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4CW7z/1/)

Comment: Thank you, it's for an experimental project, so i appreciate this may not be the proper use for the slider, although the slider will represent a time line and the the element in question will be restyled according to the chosen time period.

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what i've been trying to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one way i can think of would be:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:1,
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#someElementID").removeClass("step-" + (ui.value - 1) + " step-" + (ui.value + 1)).addClass("step-" + ui.value);
    }
});
```

Another would be:  <sub>prolly better way here</sub>

```
var araClasses = new Array("step-one", "step-two", "step-three", "step-four", "step-five", "step-six", "step-seven", "step-eight", "step-nine", "step-ten");

$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:0,
    min: 0,
    max: 9,
    change: function( event, ui ) { // change event is fired no matter how the slider is changed
        //  First remove all step classes
        for (x in araClasses) { $("#someElementID").removeClass(araClasses[x]) };
        // then add the relavant one
        $("#someElementID").addClass(araClasses[ui.value]);
    }
});
```